# Splitting Fields

Tags: galois-theory

**This is a problem from Hungerford's book:**

Let $E$ be an intermediate field of extension $K\subset F$ and assume that $E=K(u_1, \cdots ,u_r)$ where $u_i$ are (some of the) roots of $f\in K[x]$. Then $F$ is a splitting field of $f$ over $K$ if and only if $F$ is a splitting field of $f$ over E.

This is my attempt.

Let $u_1, \cdots ,v_n$ be the roots of $f$. Then since $F$ is a splitting field of $f$ over $K$, $F=K(v_1, \cdots ,v_n)$ $\implies$ $F=E(v_1, \cdots ,v_n)$. So $F$ is a splitting field of $f$ over $E$ .

Conversely, suppose $v_1, \cdots ,v_n$ are the roots of $f$ in $F$.  Then $F=E(v_1, \cdots ,v_n)=K(u_1, \cdots ,u_r,v_1, \cdots, v_n)$. Thus $F$ is a splitting field of $f$ over $K$.

**My Question:** First I want to know if the proof above is right. The second part of the problem asks to extend the above to splitting fields of arbitrary  ***set of polynomials*.** This is where I'm lost. I'd like a little help on how to begin.
Thanks.

**Update:**  I think I've got it now. I had some difficulty with the indexing. Thanks.

Comment: There's nothing to do here other than understand and unpack the definition of "splitting field" twice. I recommend you try to do this yourself.  If you continue to have difficulty, your next question should be something more elementary about the definition / concept of a splitting field.

Comment: @Pete: yeah I saw trick after posting the question. Thanks.lol

Comment: After two months, perhaps you can start asking questions instead of just copying problems and giving orders?

Comment: @Arturo: Sorry for the mistake. It wasn't my intention to give orders. It won't happen again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\left(\implies\right)$ Let $v_{1},\cdots,v_{n}$ be the roots of
$f$ in $F$. Since $F$ is a splitting field of $f$ over $K$, $F=K\left(v_{1,}\cdots,v_{n}\right)$
which implies that $F=E\left(v_{1},\cdots,v_{n}\right)$. So $F$
is a splitting field of $f$ over $E$.

$\left(\Longleftarrow\right)$ Suppose $v_{1},\cdots,v_{n}$ are the
roots of $f$ in $F$. Then $F=E\left(v_{1},\cdots,v_{n}\right)$.
But each $u_{i}$ is a one of the $v_{j}$, so $F=E\left(v_{1},\cdots,v_{r}\right)=K\left(u_{1},\cdots,u_{r},v_{1},\cdots,v_{n}\right)$.

Thus $F$ is a splitting field of $f$ over $K$.